# "Double" ManyToMany relationship between models in PlayFramework

Tags: mysql, playframework-1.x

i'm new to this forum, and also new to Play Framework. I'm doing diploma work and I have a little problem, regarding the Play models, which get mapped in MySQL schema entities.

Basically, I have the "Announce" and "Technology" entities (models), and I want to make "double" ManyToMany relationship between them. To be more specific, I want "RequiredTecnologies" and "Good-To-KnowTechnologies" cross-tables. Is there any way to "split" these two tables? Here's the code which generates one ManyToMany table, with repeating column "id" refferencing the announce.

```
// ENTITY ANNOUNCE
...
@Entity
public class Announce extends Model {

    ...
    @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Technology> reqTechno;

    @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Tehnologija> gtkTechno;
    ...
}

// ENTITY TECHNOLOGY
...
@Entity
public class Technology extends Model {

    ...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "reqTechno")
public List<Announce> annRT;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "gtkTechno")
public List<Announce> annGT;
    ...
}
```

This code generates table in MySQL in the following manner:

```
annRT_id  reqTechno_id  annGT_id  gtkTechno_id
______________________________________________
       1             2         1             7
       1             3         1             9
    null          null         1            10
       2             4         2             7
```

My desired outcome is:

```
    annRT_id  reqTechno_id       annGT_id  gtkTechno_id
__________________________       ______________________
       1             2                  1             7
       1             3                  1             9
       2             4                  1            10
                                        2             7
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

P.S. The Play version I'm using is v. 1.2.5.

Comment: Have you tried to use @JoinColumn(nullable=false) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @JoinTable to specify a different table name for each one.
Something like:

```
@ManyToMany(...)
@JoinTable(name="Announce_reqTechno")
public List<Technology> reqTechno;


@ManyToMany(...)
@JoinTable(name="Announce_gtkTechno")
public List<Technology> gtkTechno;
```